# R separate variables in one row of multiple columns into multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 563 columns.

Each column currently has one row containing multiple values of different length.

For example:

```
col_1            col_2               col_3       ...   col_563  
c("1","2","3")   c("1","2","3"...)   c("1","2")        c("1","2","3"...)
```

I want to separate the value in the columns into multiple rows:

```
col_1     col_2   col_3   ...   col_563  
"1"       "1"     "1"           "1"
"2"       "2"     "2"           "2"
"3"       "3"                   "3"
          "4"                   "4" 
          "5"
```

I have tried:

```
separate_rows(df, "row1":"row563", convert = TRUE)
```

But I got the error:

```
Error in `fn()`:
! In row 1, can't recycle input of size 778 to size 124.
```

Does anyone know how I should proceed?

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(c(df), \`length<-\`, max(lengths(c(df)))))`

Comment: @onyambu thanks so much! unfortunately I got this error:
`Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
Show in New Window
 Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE, : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 259, 41, 22, 5, 21, 7, 40, 31, 64, 36, 18, 54, 19, 88, 184, 35, 15, 24, 34, 2, 20, 4, 6, 69, 44, 13, 43, 80, 17, 9, 76, 10, 81, 3, 1, 26, 84, 57, 47, 11, 12, 16, 29, 33, 8, 14, 28, 30, 38, 210, 163, 99, 45, 108, 48, 91, 25, 23, 101, 111, 75, 65, 193, 179, 27, 58, 46, 109, 42, 53, 52, 77, 37, 127, 274, 62, 113`

Comment: what is the result of `max(lengths(c(df)))`

Comment: @onyambu the result is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Base R:

```
a <- unlist(df, FALSE)
data.frame(lapply(a, `length<-`, max(lengths(a))))

  col_1 col_2 col3 col_5
1     1     1    1     1
2     2     2    2     2
3     3     3   NA     3
4    NA     4   NA     4
5    NA     5   NA    NA
```

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

flatten(df) %>%
   map_dfc(`length<-`, max(length(.)))

    # A tibble: 4 x 4
  col_1 col_2  col3 col_5
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3    NA     3
4    NA     4    NA     4
```

where the data looks as:

```
df <- structure(list(col_1 = list(1:3), col_2 = list(1:5), col3 = list(
1:2), col_5 = list(1:4)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: what does 'length<-' do in the function?

Comment: It pads a vector with `NAs` to set it to a particular predefined length eg `a <- 1:2` then if you run `length(a) <- 10` then look at `a` you will notice that it has been padded with `NA's` and is now of length 10. @Linda